# 3d transformation n00b needs help for open source mod

Tags: 3d, matrix, transformation, minecraft

Hey all. I need help with some 3d rotations. I do not do much game development and barely remember what I did learn in academia. I am rendering a 2d image in a 3d world (Minecraft) and have the player's target coordinates aligned to the bottom left of the image.

- The plane of XZ is the walkable surface in the game
- Y is Vertical
- Image will always be at 90 degree angles

The problem is when I try to render the image horizontally, it mostly does not work. Sometimes it will be horizontal sometimes vertical. When i render vertically, it works beautifully. I'm sure its bad math. I trial and errored my way through most of this.  Pitch and yaw are viewing angles with respect to the player. This is what i'm trying to use to set the image position and orientation.

This is for an open source Minecraft server plugin. Feel free to take a look:

https://bukkit-modders.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

Additionally, if you see the logic can be reduced by using some more matrix/vector voodoo, please feel free to comment.

```
    private Matrix4d calculateOrientation(Player player) {

    Matrix4d orientation = new Matrix4d();
    orientation.setIdentity();

    Location location = player.getLocation();

    Matrix4d rotY = new Matrix4d();
    rotY.setIdentity();

    double yaw = Math.abs(location.getYaw());

    yaw %= 360;

    double baseAngle = 0;
    int sign = (location.getYaw() < 0) ? -1 : 1;

    if (yaw > (90 - 45) & yaw < (90 + 45)) {
        baseAngle = 90;
    } else if (yaw > (180 - 45) & yaw < (180 + 45)) {
        baseAngle = 180;
    } else if (yaw > (270 - 45) && yaw < (270 + 45)) {
        baseAngle = 270;
    }

    // Alight the left edge with the targeted location
    //I have no idea why this works.
    if (sign > 0) {
        baseAngle -= 180;
        rotY.rotY(Math.toRadians(baseAngle));
    } else {
        baseAngle += 180;
        rotY.rotY(Math.toRadians(baseAngle));
    }

    Matrix4d rotXZ = new Matrix4d();
    rotXZ.setIdentity();

    double rotX = 0;
    double rotZ = 0;

    if (location.getPitch() > 45) {
        //Rendering Flat in the plane of XZ
        //This block is pretty broken
        if (baseAngle == 0) {
            rotX = 90;
        } else if (baseAngle == 90) {
            rotZ = 90;
        } else if (baseAngle == 180) {

        } else if (baseAngle == 270) {
            rotZ = -90;
        }
    }

    rotXZ.rotX(Math.toRadians(rotX));
    rotXZ.rotZ(Math.toRadians(rotZ));

    orientation.mul(rotXZ);
    orientation.mul(rotY);

    return orientation;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I have my answer but have not implemented the solution yet. In summary, rotations about the Y are bad when > 90 degrees and instead should should use equivalent combinations of X and X rotations.

Something about a right handed coordinate system and some crazy matrixy math!